# Git/Maven: How do I delete and then reapply a tag?

Tags: git, maven

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 and Git.  When I run my standard

```
mvn clean deploy -P qa
```

which will deploy a build to our QA environment, I want to tag the deployed version of the code with a "qa_release" tag.  Problem is, if I have already tagged the code before, tagging it a second time won't work.  How do I delete the tag and then re-apply it?  Currently, I'm using the maven-scm-plugin to tag, but it doesn't appear it can delete tags ...

```
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <tag>qa_release</tag>
                        <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tag</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>tag</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Thanks, - Dave